# Triangulations of the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, circles, triangulation

> How many "different" triangulations does $S^1$ have? Let us say that two triangulations $T, T'$ of a space $X$ are "the same" if there is a homeomorphism $f:X \to X$ such that, for every $k, f$ identifies each $k-$simplex of $T$ with another $k-$simplex of $T'$.

Classical triangulations of $S^1$ are the following: $S^1$ in itself, with $2$ vertices and $2$ edges, an equilateral triangle, a square and so on. More generally, the circle can be viewed as a "curved" regular $n-$gon, and this are triangulations of $S^1$ (where the $1-$gon is the circle itself with one edge and one vectex, and the $2-$gon the the circle with $2$ vertices and $2$ edges). Also, these triangulations are "different", since they have a different number of vertices ($0-$simplex) and edges ($1-$simplex). However, how do we prove there aren't any other triangulations?

Comment: Your first example doesn't sound like a triangulation to me (2 vertices, 2 edges.)

Comment: Oh yes you are right, the intersections of the edges consists of both vertices, not just a unique one.

Comment: By the way, you might be able to get away with just Euler characteristic considerations. $\chi(S^1)=0$, so all you need to show is that for a finite graph, every vertex has 2 edges connected to it, and then argue that this is just an n-gon.

Comment: So the circle has $n$ different triangulations as long as $n\neq 2$?

Comment: @AndresMejia You are right, using the fact that $\chi(S^1) = 0$, we get that every triangulation has an equal number of vertices and edges, and each vertex is connected to exactly $2$ edges, and this graph is just the $n-$gon. Thank you!